# Report subscription for email delivery in SSRS

Tags: email, reporting-services, subscription

I have an SSRS report. I tried to create a subscription asking an email delivery of the report to my mail account, but it fails, giving this error message:

> The email address of one or more recepients is not valid.

I have a Browser role.

Could anyone tell me the reason?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues that could cause this:

Using an e-mail alias in combination with Windows Vista or Windows Server 2008 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945601)

The Report Server does not have permission to relay e-mail through the Exchange Server
(http://blogs.technet.com/jonathanalmquist/archive/2008/04/01/scheduled-reports-email-address-not-valid.aspx)

Comment: That first one is a killer. We recently upgraded Exchange from 2003 to 2010 (on windows server 2008) and of course updated the SSRS configuration to use the new SMTP server address... and all of the email subscriptions on SSRS 2005 were suddenly broken. What's worse is that when you create a subscription, it defaults to putting in your e-mail alias (windows user name)!
If the user on SSRS has the 'browser' role then they are able to create a subscription, but not allowed to change the email addresses! Which are wrong by default! Comedy of errors!

Comment: It also broke the SSRS 2008 R2 subscriptions. Haven't tested SSRS 2012 yet.  Also, when I said windows server 2008, I meant R2 service pack 1.

Answer (score 1):

I had some trouble with this initially too.  My problem was I was delimiting email addresses with commas when SSRS wants semicolons.